# HTTP протокол

Tags: документация, http

Встал вопрос MIME типа возвращаемого сервером (какой тип чему соответствует). Когда-то видел такую доку, сейчас не могу найти. Предлагаю, всем, поделиться наиболее важными ссылками, с пояснением, под данной тематике (протокол HTTP).

Answer (score 3):

На этом ресурсе есть весьма увестстый список MIME-типов со ссылками на соответствующие RFC не только для MIME-типизации как таковой, но и для конкртеных типов:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/

Здесь есть подборка основных типов со ссылками на основные RFC по MIME-типам

http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp